# Passing a union type into React's useRef doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

Is there a reason why React's `useRef` type implementation doesn't allow me to use a union type?

I'm not very experienced in TS, thus can't quite understand the reason from the error and the underlying typings.

[TS playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4BYAKCswFcA7DYCeuAFSQGcYAKASjgBvKnFFw0LbnCKY4AXkTEYAOlqckyTAB4AEmwCyAGQCS9MLRgBRADZIQSevAA+cPUYBCFmCxt2HMAD4eelpraz4KakoxaSQYWihWfRQYAAtlKBR6ABNcfhEYsQB+OC1gMwtYzDlBGQBfOAB6AILCuAAuUoAjLxYqmvqArUaemG96ANI20So6qiA)

```
function Test() {
    const ref = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement | HTMLButtonElement>(null);

    return Math.random()
        ? <input ref={ref} />
        : <button ref={ref}></button>;        
}
```

Error:

```
Type 'RefObject<HTMLInputElement | HTMLButtonElement>' is not assignable to type 'string | ((instance: HTMLButtonElement | null) => void) | RefObject<HTMLButtonElement> | null | undefined'.
  Type 'RefObject<HTMLInputElement | HTMLButtonElement>' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<HTMLButtonElement>'.
    Type 'HTMLInputElement | HTMLButtonElement' is not assignable to type 'HTMLButtonElement'.
      Type 'HTMLInputElement' is not assignable to type 'HTMLButtonElement'.
        Types of property 'labels' are incompatible.
          Type 'NodeListOf<HTMLLabelElement> | null' is not assignable to type 'NodeListOf<HTMLLabelElement>'.
            Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'NodeListOf<HTMLLabelElement>'.  TS2322
```

React's typings (so that you don't need to look them up):

```
interface ClassAttributes<T> extends Attributes {
    ref?: LegacyRef<T>;
}

type Ref<T> = { bivarianceHack(instance: T | null): void }["bivarianceHack"] | RefObject<T> | null;
type LegacyRef<T> = string | Ref<T>;

function useRef<T>(initialValue: T|null): RefObject<T>;

interface RefObject<T> {
    readonly current: T | null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
import React from 'react';

function Test() {
    const ref = React.useRef<HTMLInputElement | HTMLButtonElement | null>(null);

    return Math.random()
        ? <input ref={(instance) => ref.current = instance} />
        : <button ref={(instance) => ref.current = instance}></button>;        
}
```

You need to specify null if you have strict null checks (all types don't have undefiened | null in them) + ref has multiple signatures so typescript can't determine the correct one.

Comment: Thanks. Why omitting the `null` from the union type then makes the `ref.current = instance` fail on `readonly` check is beyond me :)